# Uma mesma variável ser usada por métodos diferentes, mas a segunda não pega a informação capturada pelo primeiro

Tags: c#

Pergunta de iniciante que está apanhando para aprender.

Seguinte: tenho uma variável "taxaDI".

Capturo essa informação pelo método CapturarTaxaDI().

Depois, esse valor deve ser inserido em um banco de dados pelo InserirBanco().

O que acontece é que não estou conseguindo trazer o valor capturado pelo primeiro método para o segundo inserir no banco.

Quando tento inserir no banco ele insere "0".

Acho que deveria usar uma propriedade, mas não domino isso ainda...

````cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CapturaFTP
{
    class CapturaFTP

    {   


        public static void CapturarTaxaDI()
        {       
                Campos item = new Campos();

                string data = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyyMMdd");

                string arquivoFtp = data + "_TAXA_DI.TXT";


                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@Constantes.FTP + arquivoFtp);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;


                WebProxy proxyConfigs = new WebProxy(Constantes.proxy, Constantes.portaProxy);
                proxyConfigs.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                proxyConfigs.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constantes.usuario, Constantes.senha, Constantes.dominio);
                request.Proxy = proxyConfigs;


                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string taxa = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();

                 item.taxaDI = Convert.ToDecimal(taxa) / 10000;}


               public static void InsereBanco()

               {
                Campos item = new Campos();

                SqlConnection conexaoBanco = new SqlConnection(Constantes.Banco);
                conexaoBanco.Open();

                SqlCommand comandoBanco = new SqlCommand(Constantes.judsp001InsereValorDolarSelic, conexaoBanco);

                comandoBanco.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comandoBanco.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vr_indice", item.taxaDI);
                comandoBanco.Parameters.AddWithValue("@co_indice_economico", Constantes.coIndiceTaxaDI);

                int rowsAffected = comandoBanco.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }


                class Campos
                {
                    public decimal taxaDI { get; set;}
                }


        }
    }
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os objetos declarados dentro de um método são diferentes dos criados em outros métodos, mesmo que tenham mesmo nome e tipo. Como o `item` que é declarado dentro do método `insereBanco` não é alterado, as propriedades têm o valor default (0, no caso do decimal).

Uma forma rápida de corrigir isso seria ter o objeto como parâmetro do método, fazendo `InsereBanco(Campos item)` e passando o item criado quando chamar esse método.